# How to pass parameters to a CodeActivity in a NativeActivity code sequence

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I'm trying to get windows workflows working, and I've become a little stumped.

I've gotten a single workflow working, but now I am trying to do something a little more complex: start a workflow, where each activity itself contains a workflow. (Picture something like the main program starts the activities "Input, logic, and output", and then each of those have additional activities like "prompt user, get input, etc.")

I've had it working fine, with the example from here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg535667.aspx), when I am not passing any parameters from the main program to the activites. My question is, how exactly does the 'Variables' and 'metadata.SetVariablesCollection' work in the NativeActivity, and how to I get the parameters to the low level activities?

This is what I am currently trying:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Activities;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Activities.Statements;

namespace Project1
{
    internal class MainProgram
    {
        internal static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var act = new SimpleSequence();

                act.Activities.Add((Activity)(new WriteSomeText()));
                act.Activities.Add((Activity)(new WriteSomeText()));
                act.Activities.Add((Activity)(new WriteSomeText()));

                act.Variables.Add(new Variable<string> ("stringArg", "TEXT"));

                WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(act);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: {0}", ex);
            }
        }

        public class WriteSomeText : CodeActivity
        {
            [RequiredArgument]
            public InArgument<string> stringArg { get; set; }

            protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
            {
                string output = context.GetValue(stringArg);
                System.Console.WriteLine(output);
            }

        }

        public class SimpleSequence : NativeActivity
        {
            Collection<Activity> activities;
            Collection<Variable> variables;

            Variable<int> current = new Variable<int> { Default = 0 };

            public Collection<Activity> Activities
            {
                get
                {
                    if (this.activities == null)
                        this.activities = new Collection<Activity>();

                    return this.activities;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.activities = value;
                }
            }

            public Collection<Variable> Variables
            {
                get
                {
                    if (this.variables == null)
                        this.variables = new Collection<Variable>();

                    return this.variables;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.variables = value;
                }
            }

            protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
            {
                metadata.SetChildrenCollection(this.activities);
                metadata.SetVariablesCollection(this.variables);
                metadata.AddImplementationVariable(this.current);
            }

            protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
            {
                if (this.Activities.Count > 0)
                    context.ScheduleActivity(this.Activities[0], onChildComplete);
            }

            void onChildComplete(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance completed)
            {
                int currentExecutingActivity = this.current.Get(context);
                int next = currentExecutingActivity + 1;

                if (next < this.Activities.Count)
                {
                    context.ScheduleActivity(this.Activities[next], this.onChildComplete);

                    this.current.Set(context, next);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ends up throwing the following exception:

```
EXCEPTION: System.Activities.InvalidWorkflowException: The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree:
'WriteSomeText': Value for a required activity argument 'stringArg' was not supplied.
'WriteSomeText': Value for a required activity argument 'stringArg' was not supplied.
'WriteSomeText': Value for a required activity argument 'stringArg' was not supplied.
   at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.ThrowIfViolationsExist(IList`1 validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.ValidateWorkflow(WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager)
   at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.RegisterExtensionManager(WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.RunInstance(WorkflowApplication instance)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity, IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow, TimeSpan timeout, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow)
   at Project1.MainProgram.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ModelingProject1\Project1\MainProgram.cs:line 25
```

I know, I only pass 1 parameter, but the exception still says that I am missing 3 parameters. I am missing something as to how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correctly declaring *stringArg* as an *InArgument* but you're not passing any value to it when calling it inside *SimpleSequence*.

You can pass something using the constructor, while constructing the all activity itself, like this:

```
public class WriteSomeText : CodeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> stringArg { get; set; }

    public WriteSomeText(string stringArg)
    {
        this.stringArg = stringArg;
    }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context
    {
        string output = context.GetValue(stringArg);
        System.Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}

// Calling the activity like this:

internal static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var act = new SimpleSequence()
    {
        Activities =
        {
            new WriteSomeText("hello"),
            new WriteSomeText("world"),
            new WriteSomeText("!")
        }
    };

    WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(act);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Also notice that is a best practice to use the constructor to initialize collections:

```
public SimpleSequence()
{
    activities = new Collection<Activity>();
    variables = new Collection<Variable>();
}
```

This way is even more intuitive to initialize the activity:

```
var act = new SimpleSequence()
{
    Activities =
    {
        new WriteSomeText("hello"),
        new WriteSomeText("world"),
        new WriteSomeText("!")
    },
    Variables =
    {
        new Variable<int>("myNewIntVar", 10),
        // ....
    }
};
```

EDIT:

There are a couple of other ways to approach the problem. [This](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21459) is your best friend while starting in the WF4 world.

Check *WF\Basic\CustomActivities\Code-Bodied* for a little push with this particular case.

Comment: You could also hard-code the *stringArg* when the next activity in your *SimpleSequence* is a *WriteSomeText* but that's nowhere near a best-practice. **Hard-coded** is a signal of that.

Comment: Thanks for that, but my question then becomes, what is the point of the "Variables" variable in the SimpleSequence? What is the intended use of that, if all the Code Activities get their parameters during construction?

Comment: You've to look to *Variable<T>* as a local variable in a regular method, used to manipulate and hold data **temporarily**. When you're constructing a custom activity is just like providing a method to be used. You don't want the user to touch local variables inside your method (either you are using a regular programming language or WF4 itself). Any input to that same method is given through *InArgument* that corresponds to an argument declaration in a method.

Comment: Your SimpleSequence, or native Sequence for that matter, contains *Collection<Variable>* for the user to use **while designing their own activity** using the designer or through code but, again, to hold and manipulate data for their particular activity, not your custom one. If you want your custom activity to be dynamic accordingly to outside "variables" you use InArguments. Hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: Bottom-line you've to look to WF4 as a way to *write code through code*. That's a simple way to put it but it's true in a way. You give custom activities (methods) for the user to call. Some NativeActivities are "holders" (like Sequence and a couple of others) for the user to do what he/she wants inside it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I'm in the process of parsing through and trying some of the things you have suggested, but the feedback is much appreciated regardless. I've had trouble finding really good documentation or examples of this sort of thing.

Comment: On more thing quicklym which I ran into while trying this: How would you to assignment to an Out or InOutArgument?

Comment: I'm giving you the input I wished to have had while starting myself. Check the link I've posted above. It was my best friend while starting and still is today. Good luck.

Comment: OutArguments are associated with the [Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987724.aspx) property if an [activity with result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466009.aspx). You can either *context.SetValue(base.Result, anyValuehere);* if inside a custom activity or [Assign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647739.aspx) activity if assigning from the outside. Again, look at the samples. Any new issue, please open a new question. Cheers